# 'AnyObject' is not convertible to 'String'

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

I've got this error when i try to query the parse database. I'm using this code found into the parse documentation and modified a bit. I need to take all records saved into 'elencoBirre' table, my 'test' variable is of type 'AnyObject' and i'm not able to "convert" this to a simple String, i don't get how to do. I've tried to force 'as NSString/String' but when i launch the app it stuck.

```
var appoggio2 = [String]()  

func loadDataCarrello(){

    self.appoggio2.removeAll()
    var findTimelineData:PFQuery = PFQuery (className: "Carrello")
    findTimelineData.whereKeyExists("elencoBirre")
    findTimelineData.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock{
        (objects:[AnyObject]!, error:NSError!)->Void in
        if error == nil{
            for object in objects{
                let test:PFObject = object as PFObject

                //Here is the error 'AnyObject' is not convertible to 'String'
                self.appoggio2.append(test.objectForKey("elencoBirre"))
            }                
        }
        println(self.appoggio2)
    }        
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `objectForKey` method does not guarantee results of a specific type. To cast it and append when the cast is successful, use the following:

```
if let elencoBirre = test.objectForKey("elencoBirre") as? String {
  self.appoggio2.append(elencoBirre)
}
```

You have stated that you actually expect this object to be an array. Try this instead:

```
if let elencoBirre = test.objectForKey("elencoBirre") as? [String] {
  for str in elencoBirre {
    self.appoggio2.append(str)
  }
}
```

Comment: I tried but the program don't execute this flow, so my array is still empty!

Comment: If your array is still empty, then the object attached to your `PFObject` for the key "elencoBirre" is not a `String`. You'll have to check your data source to make sure the data is stored as you expect it to be stored.

Comment: "elencoBirre" is an Array, i need multiple Strings saved. I don't get how to save an Array of Strings.